# I can't get the Cors middleware to work in my Node.js App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I am trying to use the [Cors middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) but it is not working

I followed the simple instructions in the documentation, but I am still getting this dreaded error.

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.`

Can anyone help me? This is the index.js file of my backend API, where I try to implement the middleware.

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const http = require('http');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
let path = require('path');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let config = require('./config/config');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let recipeRouter = require('./routes/recipeRouter');
let userRouter = require('./routes/userRouter');

/// Here, I required the middleware. 

let cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
// set up DB

mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function () {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});





// Set up App
app.use(morgan('combined'));

/*

This is another attempt to get this to work. Tried it, but didn't work.  

app.use(function(req, res, next){

    const origin = req.get('origin');

   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");

   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');

  /// res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', true);

   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Cache-Control, Pragma, x-auth');


});

*/


/// Here I try to apply the middleware. 

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '50mb' }));

// !! NEW !! //


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));






app.use('/users', userRouter);
app.use('/recipes',recipeRouter);


// Set up Server

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Can anyone help? Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps since you have solved your problem, you should give back to the community you just asked for help by sharing your solution.

Comment: What is most likely happening is that the `OPTIONS` call is failing because on an exception on your api. As a result cors headers are never sent and the server responds with a 500 and no cors headers. Can you confirm that your server does not crash when the `OPTIONS` call is made?